# How to setup a webhook in Google Cloud that make the code runs in automation way

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I have connection between Google Sheets and python script that I read cells from a column then read these cells's data and then run the code to do its job.

**So basically, what I want to do is setting up a webhook or anything that Make the code runs always and catching a new data in the google sheet.**

[image: This's my envrio]

I made some searches I got 3 Apps can do this but I don't know which one is suitable

```
1- Cloud Run
2- Cloud Build API
3-Cloud Deploy
```

**and how to setup the the webhook, pretty appreciate**

Answer (score 1):

[Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler) is a fully managed cron job scheduler. It allows you to schedule virtually any job. You can automate everything, including retries in case of failure to reduce manual toil and intervention. Cloud Scheduler even acts as a single pane of glass, allowing you to manage all your automation tasks from one place.